# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') custom plugin

Tags: plugins, php, themes, css, javascript

I am developing a custom plugin and I have a big problem that I can't fix.

I need to create a couple of checkboxes in the admin panel of the plugin that would change the styles of an element in the frontend. [image]

Now I created the checkboxes as you can see and I want, when it is checked to add a classlist to another class for it to look like the selected checkbox.

```
    let checkBox = document.getElementById("vsuc_checkbox1");
    let checkClass = document.getElementById("visitor_count");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        checkClass.classList.add("visitor_count_style2");
    } else {
        checkClass.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

this is the function that makes that when I click the checkbox I get the error in the console uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vsuc_checkbox1" name="vsuc_checkbox1" value="style1" onclick="checkbox()" checked >
```

this is the declaration of the checkbox. the idea is that the checkbox works, since it sends an error, but my script does not work.

What I think the problem might be, I have enequeue in the main php file the Script.js where I have the function above, in which I am adding a classList to a class from the css and I do not know if they need to be linked as well between each other.
Any help would be much appreciated!.

Comment: This is just fundamentally not how JavaScript works. You're getting the value of a checkbox in the admin and trying to set a class on the front end. That's not going to work. JavaScript runs in the browser so if you have the admin page open and click the checkbox how is the script supposed to set a class on the front end? It can't. You need to save the value of the checkbox in the database when your plugin's settings are changed and then in your frontend markup you need to read the value from the database and set the class based on that.

Comment: I suggest reading some tutorials on the WordPress settings API to see how this is supposed to work. There are many available so retreading them in an answer who would not be a great use of anyone's time. If you run into specific problems based on that then that might be suitable for a question here.

Comment: What you're saying makes perfect sense, that's why I mentioned that I think there is a problem with that but I just don't know how to get the information from the back-end and take it to my front-end. And my code is based on wordpress tutorials, just that I did not find any on this exact situation (storing backend data and then accesing it in front-end). Just a question, if in the first snippet of code I add in that if checkbox.checked==true - I store it in a variable and then access it in FE. How should I store it and how to call it then?

Comment: Setting a variable won't work. Those aren't persistent. That's why you need the database. You can't set anything directly in the database with JavaScript either, because it doesn't run on the server. If you're using the WordPress settings API properly (you don't seem to be, as there's no PHP in your checkbox code) then WordPress will save form values in the database for you and you get get the value in PHP with `get_option()`. But honestly, if you're using tutorials that don't tell you how to _read_ a saved value then just try another one, there are many that cover this.